# pm2 command not working from a docker image

Tags: node.js, docker, process, containers, pm2

I have a pm2 command in my docker file which should run inside container when the container starts:

```
CMD ["pm2", "start", "ecosystem.local.json"]
CMD ["pm2", "logs"]
```

**Expected output:** showing logs of my process

**Actual output:** no logs but container is running.

Seems like the first command doesnt start the process because when i go inside the container and run `pm2 list` manually then i dont see any process running.

But when i run the same above commands from inside the container manually:

```
pm2 start ecosystem.local.json
pm2 list
pm2 logs
```

then i can see my process running and its logs.

So why the command `CMD ["pm2", "start", "ecosystem.local.json"]` doesnt run automatically from the docker file/image?

P.S. I also used `pm2-runtime` from https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/docker-pm2-nodejs/ but no success.

Comment: It probably starts and just exits after the `start` command has been executed - and thus your docker container exits because its command exited. The [pm2 docs on Docker](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/docker-pm2-nodejs/) suggest using `pm2-runtime ecosystem.local.json`

Comment: @cbr i updated my question

Answer (score 1):

I see you mentioning the link to pm2 docs which recommend using pm2-runtime instead of just pm2 but want to confirm you updated your Dockerfile for
`CMD ["pm2", "logs"]` to become CMD `["pm2-runtime", "logs"]`.

I was running into what sounds like a similar issue and updating to use `pm2-runtime` fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in comment, my container was getting started and immediately exiting after that. I was using `pm2` and switching to `pm2-runtime` did the work.

**Not working:**

`"start-server": "export NODE_ENV=production && cd server && ./node_modules/.bin/pm2 start index.js",`

**Working:**

`"start-server": "export NODE_ENV=production && cd server && ./node_modules/.bin/pm2-runtime start index.js",`

From Dockerfile-

`CMD ["yarn", "start-server"]`

Answer (score 0):

Varun Kumar is right.
to me add `--attach` can work

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "pm2 start ecosystem.config.js --attach --watch",
  },
```